# linalg.norm not taking axis argument

Tags: python, numpy, norm

I am using Python 3 within Pyzo. Please could you tell me why the linalg.norm function does not recognise the axis argument.

This code:

```
c = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3],[-1, 1, 4]])
d=linalg.norm(c, axis=1)
```

returns the error:

> TypeError: norm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: The `axis` argument was added in version 1.8 of numpy; see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`linalg.norm` does not accept an `axis` argument.  You can get around that with:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, c)
# array([ 3.74165739,  4.24264069])
```

Or to be faster,  implement it yourself with:

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',c,c))
# array([ 3.74165739,  4.24264069])
```

For timing:

```
timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 µs per loop

timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',c,c))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion is fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

On `numpy` versions below `1.8` `linalg.norm` does not take `axis` argument, you can use `np.apply_along_axis` to get your desired outcome, as pointed out by Warren Weckesser in the comment to the question.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg

c = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3],[-1, 1, 4]])

d = np.apply_along_axis(linalg.norm, 1, c)
```

Result:

```
>>> d
array([ 3.74165739,  4.24264069])
```

Comment: Don't know about the downvoter, but this worked for me! Small correction: you need np.linalg in your example code above. Thanks especially for comment about it not working below v1.8.

Comment: @GnomeDePlume, Thanks. In my code I import `linalg` separately, so my code works as it is. Of course, it might more elegant to import just `numpy`.

Comment: Oops, I'd overlooked that! Correction redacted :)